# angularjs ng-scrollbar not working

Tags: angularjs, scroll, angularjs-directive

im trying to implement the ng-scrollbar created by asafdav in his github: https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar, and im trying to use his example in a plunker and in my app, but i cant make it work, here is the link of the plunker im trying to solve.

http://plnkr.co/edit/suryw2ffUymZ7tW8kIxk?p=preview

sorry if my question is to basic but im kind of new with angularjs, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plnkr has 404 errors:

```
GET http://run.plnkr.co/ng-scrollbar.js 404 (Not Found) (index):8
GET http://run.plnkr.co/ng-scrollbar.min.css 404 (Not Found) (index):10
Uncaught Error: No module: ngScrollbar
```

You need to change your references to these files like this:

```
<script src="ng-scrollbar.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ng-scrollbar.min.css">
```

you had `/ng-scrollbar.js` and `/ng-scrollbar.min.css`

Comment: No problem, nice little directive that I'll have to look into using